# Can you "pretty print" JSON in Swift or Obj-C without knowing the structure of the JSON?

Tags: json, swift

I know I can use the option JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted like this:

```
    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
        let prettyJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted )
        if let prettyString = String(data: prettyJson, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(prettyString)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with Json: \(error)")
    }
```

but can I parse it myself to get output like:

```
key:
    value,
key:
    value, value,
    .
    .
    .
```

without knowing what type of key, value pair to expect? (Ex: key:String, key:Array, key: Dictionary)

Comment: You want to parse the serialized JSON and format it to look nice, like the pretty-printed version? Sure, you could, but it would be a lot of work. You'd basically have to write a JSON parser yourself, purely for the purpose of display formatting. Why would you want to do that? It's what's known as a "solved problem."

Comment: @DuncanC Writing parser is not needed - with some obvious limitations, e.g. the ordering of items in dictionaries. Writing encoder is not so difficult, however it's not trivial either.

Comment: You might like `dump(json)`

Comment: It was an exercise. No JSON format given. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the constructor `String(describing:)` to get the programmatically representation of a data element.  It should help you write your own routine to pretty print JSON however you like.